# Groupwise average in sql

Tags: sql, average

I have a table that consists of 100 rows and two columns (color, cost).

Now in total, the 100 rows consist of 5 colors (blue, black, yellow, orange, green).

So, now if I want to take the average of cost colorwise, how do I do that in SQL?

I mean, my final table should be

```
 color  | avgcost
--------+--------
 blue   |  120
 black  |  80
 yellow |  77
 orange |  84
 green  |  44
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `GROUP BY` clause to group the color and `AVG` to compute the average for each group:

```
SELECT color, AVG(cost) AS avgcost
FROM   T
GROUP  BY color;
```

Please checkout [**this demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed608/2).